# Learn VHDL when coming from strong Verilog background

Tags: vhdl, verilog, hdl

I have a strong Verilog and digital design background. I'm now in a position where I have to learn VHDL quickly, preferably in a few weeks. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Practice. (And make sure you have blood pressure pills because you will find many things which are easy in Verilog are almost impossible in VHDL. Like `$display("Error @%0t in %m, Adrs=0x%04X, expected 0x%04X",$time,adrs,exp_adrs); :-) `

Comment: Use tool that support VHDL 2008 to make some of the transition a little easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a strong base of digital design, you should definitively read Peter Ashenden's book *Designer's Guide To VHDL*. VHDL needs more code to describe a program, but it often catches errors missed by verilog, emphasizes unambiguous semantics and is portable, just to name a few. Just get familiarized with the concepts and you should be ready to understand it in no time.

Comment: I'll take a look at that book. I started by taking a look at Free Range VHDL (still going through the chapters, and it does deal with digital design for people moving over from high-lvel languages like C, and not Verilog). And I'm starting to understand what you mean by "needing more code". With so many data types, it is getting a little confusing!

Comment: Of the many VHDL books I have, this is the best and the only one I consistently reference.  Skim through the chapters to get a feel for the code layout, and bookmark the appendix with the syntax rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Digital Logic and Microprocessor Design with VHDL by Enoch Hwang.  It's a pretty easy read and you'll learn the VHDL essentials well.  You can find some sample chapters here http://faculty.lasierra.edu/~ehwang/digitaldesign/